# Console not appearing at the bottom in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

When opening chrome developer tools, the console used to come below any open tab (like elements, sources etc.). However, I cannot see it there now.
[image]

How do I put is back there again?

Comment: Options (top right), "Show console drawer"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click on the three dots `...` in the top right corner and pick *"Show console drawer"* or just press `Esc` (regardless of your OS).

Comment: `Esc`, what a unique shortcut. It can also be used to hide the console drawer.

Comment: Just press `Esc`. I'm done!!